# LocalStorage is not defined in angular2 service

Tags: angular

I'm building an angular2 app with .net core backend. I have an app guard that blocks user navigation if the user isn't authenticated to the '/app' route. If I navigate to the '/app' route through the router after the user logs in it works fine, but if I type '/app' in the address bar it tells me that localStorage is not defined.

Here's my auth guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

        if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
            // logged in so return true
            return true;
        }

        // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url

        this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *it tells me* - please, provide error message (unless it tells verbally). This is how we deal with them. We post them, not paraphrase. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . A plunk or a fiddle. The answerers should be able to replicate the issue in order to solve it.

Comment: that was hard for me to do, since it was hard to know where it was coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding isBrowser check before entering the method. Turns out the sample project I'm using pre rendered the html on the server.